# Creating object with specific keys in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I create the following object with jQuery:

```
{"41500":{"color":"black","qty":1},"41501":{"color":"red","qty":1}}
```

Comment: Hint. JSON  with arrays. Try creating some code then coming back for help if you have trouble.

Comment: Why jQuery? Plain JS will do just fine. However it is not clear what you mean.  `var obj = {"41500":{"color":"black","qty":1},"41501":{"color":"red","qty":1}}` just created your object

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a magical object notation, it's just plain ol' JS through and through.

Comment: I tried so many things, my head will explode.. Anyway, I got it working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// you'll need them in an array
var arr = [];

// make an empty object
var obj = {};

// name a key and set the value as another obj
obj["41500"] = {
  "color": "black",
  "qty": 1
}
arr.push(obj);

// repeat
var obj = {};
obj["41501"] = {
  "color": "red",
  "qty": 1
}
arr.push(obj);

console.log(arr)
```

### //UPDATE//

If you need the index to be at the value then do this:

```js
var array = [];
array[41500] = {
  "color": "black",
  "qty": 1
}
array[41501] = {
  "color": "red",
  "qty": 1
}
console.log(array[41500]);
var id = 41501;
console.log(array[id]);

// notice all the undefined values at the indexes
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Np, as a side note, you can always test your JSON at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Why an array?  `/* make an empty object */
var obj = {};

/* name a key and set the value as another obj */
obj["41500"] = {
  "color": "black",
  "qty": 1
}

/* repeat */
obj["41501"] = {
  "color": "red",
  "qty": 1
}`

Comment: Please run the snippet for the output. You will see that the log shows an array of objects. This is very helpful when working with similar objects. If you try `obj[41500]` without it being defined as an object, it will search it as an array in index 41500. Instead, we are saying be an object with a key named "41500". And insert it into an array. The index for that object is 0 instead of 41500. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery for this, just use plain JS. There are multiple ways of doing this. The easiest is:

```
var newObject = {"41500":{"color":"black","qty":1},"41501":{"color":"red","qty":1}}
```

You may also want to load is using JSON, especially if its variable and from a file.

```
var newObjectString = // the data from the file.
var newObject = JSON.parse(newObjectString)
```